# How to properly check this regex using python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to Check if the input is in this pattern : **MH12**

Starting two digits to be MH then next two digits to be any number
and The full string should be 4 digits only. so Tired with `regex = r'^[MH]\d{2}.{,4}$'`

import re

```
def checkingInput():
    while True:
        try:
            inp = raw_input()
            if re.match(r'[MH]\d{2}', inp):
                print "Thanks for your Input:",inp
                break
            else:
                print('Invalid office code, please enter again :')
        except ValueError:
                print('Value error! Please try again!')


checkingInput()
```

but the above program even for **input = MH12** it it showing Invalid Office code. Why so?

May be I am missing something?

Comment: should be r'MH\d{2}'

Comment: I think it should be `if re.match(r'MH\d{2}$', inp):`, or use `re.fullmatch` with `r'MH\d{2}'` in Python 3.4+.

Comment: @e4c5 Yeah Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern `[MH]` matches exactly one letter: either an `M` *or* an `H`.

You should use `MH` instead.

The entire regex is `MH\d\d`; in Python syntax that would be `r'MH\d\d'`.

Comment: Thanks you very much

Answer (score 1):

As you're using MH as a part of the string you're trying to match, you have to exclude the [] class from your expression, so the valid one is

```
import re

def checkingInput():
    while True:
        try:
            inp = raw_input()
            if re.match(r'MH\d{2}', inp):
                print inp
            else:
                print('Invalid office code, please enter again :')
        except ValueError:
                print('Value error! Please try again!')


checkingInput()
```

Answer (score 1):

try it：

re.findall(r'MH\d{2}', s)